# Syntax error when using import dropbox in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dropbox, dropbox-api, python-import

I'm trying to use Dropbox with Python 3.  It appears to install OK but when I try to import it, I get a syntax error (see below).  It's only supported on 3.4+ and I'm using 3.2... I wondered if that's the problem but I found a website (in the [original German](http://pi-buch.info/?p=406) or [in English](https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?sl=de&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fpi-buch.info%2F%3Fp%3D406&edit-text=&act=url) using Google Translate which doesn't get the formatting quite right) which is using Dropbox with Python 3.2 on a Raspberry Pi - and that's exactly what I want to do.

Thanks in advance - any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

```
pi@jsmd ~ $ sudo pip-3.2 install --upgrade dropbox
Requirement already up-to-date: dropbox in /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/dropbox-4.0-py3.2.egg
Requirement already up-to-date: urllib3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages (from dropbox)
Requirement already up-to-date: requests>=2.5.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages (from dropbox)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages (from dropbox)
Cleaning up...

pi@jsmd ~ $ python3.2
Python 3.2.3 (default, Mar  1 2013, 11:53:50)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import dropbox
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/dropbox-4.0-py3.2.egg/dropbox/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .dropbox import __version__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/dropbox-4.0-py3.2.egg/dropbox/dropbox.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .base import DropboxBase
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/dropbox-4.0-py3.2.egg/dropbox/base.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/dropbox-4.0-py3.2.egg/dropbox/files.py", line 5157
    Metadata._parent_shared_folder_id_validator = bv.Nullable(bv.String(pattern=u'[-_0-9a-zA-Z:]+'))
                                                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Python 3.2 doesn't support the `u'...'` string literal syntax, no. Upgrade to 3.3 at the very least.

Comment: Seems the library is incompatible with 3.2, it was a later version (3.3 or 3.4) that re-introduced the u"" string notation.

Comment: The blog post doesn't detail how they managed to skirt around this requirement. Perhaps in May 2015 the library still worked on Python 3.2 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *current version* of the provided Dropbox Python SDK uses the `u'...'` notation to define Unicode literals. This is a syntax introduced in Python 3.3 to assist in writing code that works both on Python 2 and 3.

The blog post doesn't detail how they managed to skirt the minimum requirements; I can only think that the library has been updated to take advantage of newer Python features to simplify polyglot Python code *after the post was published*.

The current `dropbox` package version is 4.0; take a look through the versions on the [simple pypi page for the package](https://pypi.python.org/simple/dropbox/) and see if an earlier version works for you, instead.

I'm not sure the version the blog used is available though. [Version 3.12](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dropbox/3.12) was published to PyPI in August 2015, so well after May 2015 (when the blog post was posted) and already requires Python 3.3 or newer (judging by the [initial API v2 commit on Github](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/tree/f72f99d83dd85d43e3a241137ca4d1ac78d9e5b3)). The next older release is [version 2.2.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dropbox/2.2.0), which goes back to September 2014 and uses Dropbox API version 1.

Comment: Hi Martijn, Remco,
Thanks, this is clearly the issue.  It looks as though I need to upgrade Python (and unfortunately the "correct" way to do that means installing a new version of the OS... but at least that will give me Python 3.4 which seems more widely supported than 3.2.)

Thanks again.
Stuart.